# Implements Compilation Check to Avoid Nested Scope in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class TransactionScope. It does not support the nested transaction, so basically I want to prevent users to use it in a nested way. Is there any way to implement a compilation check to avoid nested scope in C++.

A correct example is

```
{
  TransactionScope scope_0;
  // user code...
}

{
  TransactionScope scope_1;
  // user code...
}
```

An incorrect example is

```
{
  TransactionScope scope_0;
  {
    TransactionScope scope_1;  // nested, incorrect
    // user code...
  }
  // user code...
}
```

Comment: No, there's no way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible.

I do not like to say something is impossible; someone might come up with a clever idea that approaches the problem from a new angle. However, in this case, there is a scenario that does seem to doom the idea. (I believe it is not possible in all scenarios; the one below merely illustrates the beginning of the extent of the difficulty.)

Suppose you have a fun function named `fun()` defined in one of your source files. Let's assume that this definition is along the lines of the following:

```
void fun()
{
    TransactionScope B;
    // Do stuff
}
```

In a **different** source file, suppose you have the following function defined.

```
void foo()
{
    TransactionScope A;
    // Do stuff
    fun();
    // Do more stuff
}
```

This uses `TransactionScope` "in a nested way" – object `B` is constructed during the lifetime of `A`. Yet this fact cannot be known until the linking stage. A basic principle of translation units is that they are compiled independently. When processing the file containing the definition of `foo`, the compiler has no knowledge of the internals of `fun`, and vice versa. It is not until the linker processes all the object files that there is any chance of discovering this nested usage.

As far as the linker is concerned, everything matches up. There is a call to `void fun()` that gets linked to the definition with a matching signature. There is nothing in the language that can make this link conditional based upon the context. So there is no way for the linker to stop this nested transaction scope.